# polyfill of javascript Object create with simple form

Tags: javascript, closures, polyfills, iife

The polyfill of javascript Object.create(), by some codes in which I am totally confused. The code link is [polyfill of Object create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill).

```js
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
    // Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.2.3.5
    // Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.5
    Object.create = (function() {
        // To save on memory, use a shared constructor
        function Temp() {}

        // make a safe reference to Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
        var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

        return function(O) {
            // 1. If Type(O) is not Object or Null throw a TypeError exception.
            if (typeof O != 'object') {
                throw TypeError('Object prototype may only be an Object or null');
            }

            // 2. Let obj be the result of creating a new object as if by the
            //    expression new Object() where Object is the standard built-in
            //    constructor with that name
            // 3. Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to O.
            Temp.prototype = O;
            var obj = new Temp();
            Temp.prototype = null; // Let's not keep a stray reference to O...

            // 4. If the argument Properties is present and not undefined, add
            //    own properties to obj as if by calling the standard built-in
            //    function Object.defineProperties with arguments obj and
            //    Properties.
            if (arguments.length > 1) {
                // Object.defineProperties does ToObject on its first argument.
                var Properties = Object(arguments[1]);
                for (var prop in Properties) {
                    if (hasOwn.call(Properties, prop)) {
                        obj[prop] = Properties[prop];
                    }
                }
            }

            // 5. Return obj
            return obj;
        };
    })();
}
```

1. Why does it complicate the logic by using IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Express) and a return function, and closure.
2. Instead, can I use the simple logic and code below? Is there any wrong or inappropriate content in it? There isn't IIFE and a return function.

```js
if (typeof Object.createOwn != "function") {
    Object.createOwn = function(O) {
        // 1. if Type(O) is not Object or Null throw a TypeError exception.
        if (typeof(O) != "object") {
            throw TypeError("Object prototype may only be an Object or null");
        }

        // 2. Let obj be the result of creating a new object as if by the
        //    expression new Object() where Object is the standard built-in
        //    constructor with that name
        // 3. Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to O.
        var obj;
        var Temp = function() {};
        Temp.prototype = O;
        obj = new Temp();

        // 4. If the argument Properties is present and not undefined, add
        //    own properties to obj as if by calling the standard built-in
        //    function Object.defineProperties with arguments obj and Properties
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            var Properties = Object(arguments[1]);
            for (var prop in Properties) {
                if (Properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    obj[prop] = Properties[prop];
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

var foo = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
};

var bar = Object.createOwn(foo, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will both work, but the original is using IIFE for a few reasons. Two of them is mentioned in the comments

```
// To save on memory, use a shared constructor
```

This is not the case with your version, where `var Temp = function() {};` is wrapped into the function and a new instance is created every time you use it.

```
// make a safe reference to Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
```

Since `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` could potentially be overridden for when it's time to use it, the polyfill makes sure it has it's own safe reference to it at each `Object.create`.

Then it's also the common reason many use IIFE, to avoid polluting the global namespace.

These are mostly safeguards, and not required in this case. But I see no reason to remove them.